# Items not centering in simple flex container

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why is the button not center???!!! I'm kind of new to CSS. I learned that align-items centers child elements on the cross axis. My button isn't centering. Why isn't this working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>CSS Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Get Started"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: I tried without closing the input tag in html as well.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Besides that, you have to set both `html` and `body`'s height to 100%.

Comment: The `<input>` tag is a self-closing tag (aka only `<input />`. @code setting `<body>`'s height is enough, no need for `<html>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the height of the main parent so your CSS code would look like this:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh /* Height of the viewport (window) */
}

.button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: This will create a long scrollbar (solved with `margin: 0;` on `<body>`, also you didn't add anything new from Unmitigated's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The flex container's children will be centered according to its height. By default, the height of the body element is just enough to contain its content, so `align-items: center` has no visible effect. Set the body's height to be the height of the viewport to see the input being centered in the middle of the screen.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0; /* prevent scrollbar */
}
```

Comment: See the code working here: https://jsfiddle.net/rtxen078/